# How to parse output of dependency tree into flattened structure

Tags: python, regex, string, recursion, hierarchical-data

Okay, I am completely at a loss. I have some output from a dependency tree parsing tool that looks like the following:

```
(S 
    (NP 
        (PRP It)
    )
    (VP
        (VBD said)
        (CLAUSE
            (S
                (NP
                    (DT the)
                    (NN figure)
                )
                (VP 
                    (VBD was)
                    (VBN rounded)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (PUNC .)
)
```

These parse outputs are saved as plain-text. The output is basically a binary tree as far as I can tell. What I would like is to have an output file where each word is on a new line, and each word contains all of the labels associated with the word. An example is:

```
It  S   NP  PRP
said    S   VP
the S   VP  CLAUSE  S   NP  DT
figure  S   VP  CLAUSE  S   NP  NN
was S   VP  CLAUSE  S   VP  VBD
rounded S   VP  CLAUSE  S   VP  VBN
. PUNC  S
```

How can I parse this output into the output I'm looking for? I've attempted to use the `pyparsing` library, and have been able to parse the string into a hierarchical list of lists, but this doesn't quite match my output needs.

I think recursion is probably a good candidate tool here, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem. Any help on this would be appreciated - even pseudo-code to get the implementation idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First up, there are mistakes in your output transitions.

To approach a solution, recursion is required. But you don't have to invent the wheel. There's a nice little module called `pyparsing` just for tasks like this. We can convert that string to a nested list of lists using recursive regex:

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

astring = '''(S 
    (NP 
        (PRP It)
    )
    (VP
        (VBD said)
        (CLAUSE
            (S
                (NP
                    (DT the)
                    (NN figure)
                )
                (VP 
                    (VBD was)
                    (VBN rounded)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (PUNC .)
)'''

expr = nestedExpr('(', ')')
result = expr.parseString(astring).asList()[0]

print(result)
```

This prints out:

```
['S',
 ['NP', ['PRP', 'It']],
 ['VP',
  ['VBD', 'said'],
  ['CLAUSE',
   ['S',
    ['NP', ['DT', 'the'], ['NN', 'figure']],
    ['VP', ['VBD', 'was'], ['VBN', 'rounded']]]]],
 ['PUNC', '.']]
```

Next up, we'll need to write a function that can build transitions from the given parse tree. Sadly, there's no easy way to do this. We'll need to write a hardcore recursive subroutine ourselves. Here's one approach. Use the nth symbol and retrieve all transitions for the n+1 symbols, and then build a new list of transitions by appending the nth symbol to those transitions.

Sounds a little complicated, but maybe the code will help you understand:

```
def get_rules(rule_list):
    transitions = []

    if len(rule_list) == 2 and isinstance(rule_list[1], str):
        return [rule_list]


    for rule in rule_list[1:]:
        for r in get_rules(rule):
            transitions.append([rule_list[0]] + r)

    return transitions
```

It's pretty simple. There's a base case, where you return a singleton transition if you reach a terminal. Otherwise build transitions recursively.

Calling this function and printing the results are done next:

```
for r in get_rules(result):
    print(r[-1] + '\t' + '\t'.join(r[:-1]))
```

Output:

```
It  S   NP  PRP
said    S   VP  VBD
the S   VP  CLAUSE  S   NP  DT
figure  S   VP  CLAUSE  S   NP  NN
was S   VP  CLAUSE  S   VP  VBD
rounded S   VP  CLAUSE  S   VP  VBN
.   S   PUNC
```

I mentioned earlier that your transitions were represented incorrectly. You can cross check with this, this is the right answer.